# How to use Variables in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to use variables in my Hive script. But for some reason it isn't working.

```
SET $app_count=select max(app_id) from app_table;
SELECT '${hiveconf:app_count}',app_name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY app_name) FROM new_apps;
```

Output

```
_c0   app_name    _wcol0
      app1          1
      app2          2
      app3          3
```

Expected result: lets say the max(app_id) from another table is 10

```
_c0   app_name    _wcol0
 10    app1         1
 10    app2         2
 10    app3         3
```

Not sure why the variable value is not substituting in the query. I even used the setting

'set hive.variable.substitute=true;' . 
But it didn't make any change. Thanks in Advance. Any alternate solution is also appreciated.

Comment: Rhetorical question: do you understand what `$` means when manipulating a variable in Unix script, or Hive script? *-- hint: that's not the same thing as in Microsoft PowerShell* :-/

Comment: Another rhetorical question: did you try to check what the `SET` command actually stored in the variable? And did you expect SET to *execute* something, or just *store a literal value*?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I am running this Hive script in Azure powershell, I am not sure if that makes a difference. I have even tried with 'SET count = query;' . I am trying to assign the query result to the variable and use it in my next query.

Comment: @user3267086  This is still a open JIRA task in hive.  HIVE-2165 is the JIRA number. Try to implement the above using Hive Query Language itself.

Comment: @madhu I am not sure how to implement it in Hive Query Language. If you have a alternative solution. can you please post it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just store the result of this query in another table(test) with single column app_id.

```
select max(app_id) from app_table
```

Then you can use the below query:

```
select test.app_id,new_apps.app_name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY new_apps.app_name) FROM new_apps join test;
```